# Representations of finite abelian groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and let $V$ be a finite-dimensional irreducible representation of $G$ over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$.  Is it the case that the action of $G$ on $V$ factors through a cyclic group?

This is easy if $k$ is algebraically closed, and I'm pretty sure it is true in general (but I can't seem to prove it or find a suitable reference).

Comment: You need the result that every finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic. The easiest way to prove this is by using that a polynomial of degree $d$ has at most $d$ roots and that a finite abelian group is cyclic if and only if it's order is its exponent.

Comment: (To apply the previous comment you need to observe that the subalgebra generated by the image of $G$ is a field.)

Comment: Ah, I see: the point is that since $G$ is abelian, the image of $G$ in $End(V)$ lies in $End_G(V)$, which is a division ring.  You then argue that the subalgebra generated by the image of $G$ in $End_G(V)$ is a commutative division ring (I guess you have to show that it is closed under inverses?), and thus a field.  It then follows from the standard fact that Simon quotes.  Is this a correct summary?

Comment: @Miranda for nonzero $f$ in this subalgebra, $f^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $f$ so is in the subalgebra too.

Comment: @YCor: Ah, good point, thanks to all!